# Perform action while jQuery UI modal dialog is open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div element which on clicking on it opens a jQuery UI modal dialog window. What I want to do is highlight the div element(meaning change its color) for the duration that the modal dialog is open and revert it back to its original state on closing the dialog window. Is it possible to do so?

Changing the background-color using the .css method isn't working like I want it to. My code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="help" class="hover">Help</div>

<div id="helpdialog" class="helpbox">
<header id="helptitle">Help</header>    
<p id="helptext">
</p>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#help').on('click',function() {
$('#help').css('background-color','#F0E68C');
$( "#helpdialog" ).dialog({
height: 670,
width: 570,
modal: true,
draggable: true,
resizable: false,
dialogClass: "helpbox",
buttons: { Close: function() { $(this).dialog("close");
$('#help').css('background-color',''); } },
create: function(event, ui)  
{  
$(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("display","none");       
$(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("padding", 0);  
$(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("border", '1em solid #709CB4');
$(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("border-radius", '0.6em');    
$(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-content").css("padding",0);  
}  
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [close](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) and [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) events

```
$('#help').on('click', function() {

    $("#helpdialog").dialog({
        height : 670,
        width : 570,
        modal : true,
        draggable : true,
        resizable : false,
        dialogClass : "helpbox",
        buttons : {
            Close : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        create : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar")
                    .css("display", "none");
            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("padding", 0);
            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("border", '1em solid #709CB4');
            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("border-radius", '0.6em');
            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-content").css(
                    "padding", 0);
        },
        open : function(event, ui) {
            $('#help').css('background-color', '#F0E68C');
        },
        close : function(event, ui) {
            $('#help').css('background-color', '');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In the CSS,my #help div has background-color set as #E2ECEB. I'm being able to change its color on closing the dialog,not while it is open.

Comment: seems to be working fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/mpgIr5DGzv2RGYaJV7JW?p=preview

Comment: Oh yes it's working,I was making a mistake. My mouseout function on the hover class was causing the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
$('#help').css('background-color','');
```

Set some color

```
$('#help').css('background-color','#aaa');
```

Comment: No well that's not the problem.The color does not change to #F0E68C either while the dialog is open. It just stays in its default color. The rest of the page dims in color as expected but I was hoping to keep the #help div colored while the dialog is open on the screen.